# Installing LAMP stack on Ubuntu 10.X Desktop version

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, lamp

I want to install LAMP stack on Ubuntu desktop version `10.x`.  Do I have to reinstall the whole thing via the server version or `apt-get install`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Just open a Terminal and type the following:

`sudo tasksel install lamp-server`

If you want to bring up the whole menu for the application groups:
`sudo tasksel`

You can use the Ubuntu help these times (if you get stuck):
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP

Comment: Like Shiki said. Have fun with LAMP. It's great fun!